# Some Errors in my X and O game ( C language)

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, while-loop, boolean

What I'm trying to do here is a tie toe game, but when my code enters the do - while part, it ends the process by itself. Since I could not solve this part, I did not have a chance to try whether there are other problems with the code, unfortunately, I would be glad if you could help with this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


char box_area[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' };
struct Player {
    bool turn;
    char mark;
    int ID;

};

int main()
{
    int return_result;
    int player_number;
    struct Player player1;
    struct Player player2;
    struct Player users[2];
    users[0] = player1;
    users[1] = player2;
    
    
    (player1.mark = 'X') && (player2.mark = 'O');
    (player1.turn = true) && (player2.turn = false);
    (player1.ID = 1) && (player2.ID = 2); 
  
    do 
    {
        box_creat();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (users[i].turn == true) 
            {
                make_move(users[i].ID);
                box_creat();
                users[i].turn = false;
                users[i + 1].turn = true; \\ I made the logic of this section wrong
                            \\I will try to fix it, I realized after I sent the question 
            }

        }
        return_result = check_the_winner();
        

    } while (return_result == 1 || return_result == -1);
 
    

    return 0;
}
void box_creat(void) {
    printf("| %c | %c | %c |", box_area[0], box_area[1], box_area[2]);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("| %c | %c | %c |", box_area[3], box_area[4], box_area[5]);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("| %c | %c | %c |", box_area[6], box_area[7], box_area[8]);
}
void make_move(int Player_ID) 
{
    int choice;
    printf("Please select a area between 0-9 ");
    scanf("%d", choice);
    if (choice == '0' && box_area[0] == '0') 
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1) {
            box_area[0] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            box_area[0] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == '1' && box_area[1] == '1')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1) {
            box_area[1] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            box_area[1] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == '2' && box_area[2] == '2')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1) {
            box_area[2] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            box_area[2] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == '3' && box_area[3] == '0')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1) {
            box_area[3] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            box_area[3] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == '4' && box_area[4] == '0')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1) {
            box_area[4] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            box_area[4] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == '5' && box_area[5] == '0')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1) {
            box_area[5] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            box_area[5] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == '6' && box_area[6] == '0')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1) {
            box_area[6] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            box_area[6] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == '7' && box_area[7] == '0')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1) {
            box_area[7] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            box_area[7] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == '8' && box_area[8] == '0')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1) {
            box_area[8] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            box_area[8] = 'O';

        }

    }

}
int check_the_winner(void)
{
    if (box_area[0] && box_area[1] && box_area[2] == 'X' || 'O') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(box_area[3] && box_area[4] && box_area[5] == 'X' || 'O') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (box_area[6] && box_area[7] && box_area[8] == 'X' || 'O') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (box_area[2] && box_area[4] && box_area[6] == 'X' || 'O') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (box_area[0] && box_area[3] && box_area[6] == 'X' || 'O') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (box_area[2] && box_area[8] && box_area[5] == 'X' || 'O') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (box_area[0] && box_area[4] && box_area[8] == 'X' || 'O') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (box_area[1] && box_area[4] && box_area[7] == 'X' || 'O') {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This if condition uses assignment operator instead of comparison operator. `if (users[i].turn = true)`. You should use `if (users[i].turn == true)`

Comment: Also this check doesn’t look correct. `box_area[2] == 'X' || 'O'`. In C you can’t compare like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your program and found a few glitches that needed revision as well as adding in some additional bits of code just to neaten things up a bit.  Following is your code with those revisions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char box_area[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' };

struct Player
{
    bool turn;
    char mark;
    int ID;

};

void box_creat(void)
{
    printf("| %c | %c | %c |", box_area[0], box_area[1], box_area[2]);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("| %c | %c | %c |", box_area[3], box_area[4], box_area[5]);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("| %c | %c | %c |", box_area[6], box_area[7], box_area[8]);
    printf("\n");                                       /* Added for aesthetics */
}
void make_move(int Player_ID)
{
    int choice;
    printf("Player %d - please select a area between 0-9 ", Player_ID);
    scanf("%d", &choice);                               /* Corrected missing ampersand */
    printf("Player: %d makes a move\n", Player_ID);
    if (choice == 0 && box_area[0] == '0')              /* FYI - '0' is equivalent to integer value 48 */
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1)
        {
            box_area[0] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            box_area[0] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == 1 && box_area[1] == '1')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1)
        {
            box_area[1] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            box_area[1] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == 2 && box_area[2] == '2')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1)
        {
            box_area[2] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            box_area[2] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == 3 && box_area[3] == '3')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1)
        {
            box_area[3] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            box_area[3] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == 4 && box_area[4] == '4')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1)
        {
            box_area[4] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            box_area[4] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == 5 && box_area[5] == '5')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1)
        {
            box_area[5] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            box_area[5] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == 6 && box_area[6] == '6')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1)
        {
            box_area[6] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            box_area[6] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == 7 && box_area[7] == '7')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1)
        {
            box_area[7] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            box_area[7] = 'O';

        }

    }
    else if (choice == 8 && box_area[8] == '8')
    {
        if (Player_ID == 1)
        {
            box_area[8] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            box_area[8] = 'O';

        }

    }

}
int check_the_winner(void)
{
    if     ((box_area[0] ==  box_area[1]) && (box_area[1] == box_area[2]) && (box_area[0] != '0'))  /* Corrected the testing for proper "and" conditioning */
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((box_area[3] == box_area[4]) && (box_area[4] == box_area[5]) && (box_area[3] != '3'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((box_area[6] == box_area[7]) && (box_area[7] == box_area[8]) && (box_area[6] != '6'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((box_area[2] == box_area[4]) && (box_area[4] == box_area[6]) && (box_area[2] != '2'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((box_area[0] == box_area[3]) && (box_area[3] == box_area[6]) && (box_area[0] != '0'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((box_area[2] == box_area[5]) && (box_area[5] == box_area[8]) && (box_area[2] != '2'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((box_area[0] == box_area[4]) && (box_area[4] == box_area[8]) && (box_area[4] != '4'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((box_area[1] == box_area[4]) && (box_area[4] == box_area[7]) && (box_area[1] != '1'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int return_result;
    //int player_number;                /* Compiler said that this wasn't being used */
    int swap = 1;
    int i;
    struct Player player1;
    struct Player player2;
    struct Player *users[2];            /* Used these as address pointers to player "1" and player "2" */
    users[0] = &player1;                /* Before making these pointers, the users array just contained copies of the player structures */
    users[1] = &player2;

    (player1.mark = 'X') && (player2.mark = 'O');
    (player1.turn = true) && (player2.turn = false);
    (player1.ID = 1) && (player2.ID = 2);

    do
    {
        box_creat();

            swap += 1;
            i = swap % 2;

            if (i == 1)
            {
                make_move(users[1]->ID);
                //box_creat();              /* Being performed at the top of the loop */
                users[0]->turn = false;
                users[1]->turn = true;
            }
            else
            {
                make_move(users[0]->ID);
                //box_creat();
                users[1]->turn = false;
                users[0]->turn = true;
            }

        return_result = check_the_winner();

        if (check_the_winner() == 1)        /* Added when a winner has been sensed */
        {
            box_creat();
            if (i == 1)
            {
                printf("Player 2 won!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Player 1 won!\n");
            }
        }

    }
    while (return_result != 1);

    return 0;
}
```

I added comments to most of the places I had tweaked, but here are the highlights:

- I shuffled some of the functions around so that the "main" function followed all of the helper functions (the compiler was giving warnings about the original sequence of the function positions).
- I corrected the "choice" tests as "choice" is an integer, so the test of "choice" needed to be compared to an integer value (e.g. zero) as opposed to character '0' (which actually has a value of 48).
- The tests for three letters in a row for either player do not work in that manner.  Either a test needed to be made for each box for a certain row needed to tested for an "X" or an "O", and then if that test was true the test needed to be continued for the next box in the row, and then again for the third box in the row.  In lieu of that route, the test was revised to basically say "if the character in the first box in the row is the same as the character in the second box in the row, and the character in the second box in the row is the same as the character in the third box in the row, and the first box does not contain a digit character (which means is contains an "X" or an "O"), then there is a winner.
- It appears that an attempt was made to mirror the contents of "Player1" and "Player2" into an array of player structures.  Although initially, structure "users[0]" contained the same data as "Player1" and structure "users[1]" contained the same data as "Player2", once the data in "Player1" and "Player2" were updated, those changes did to propagate over to the "users" array.  So to utilize "users" in the spirit of this program, they were defined as pointers to their respective player structures.

Those were the most significant bits.  The other bits were added for a logical conclusion of the game.  Note that no logic was added for a draw.

Give that a test and see if that clarifies things and follows the spirit of the project.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I have two question. I wanted to try to swap the players using with true and false statments, and you did it by adding swap(added by you), but you continued to use the (.turn) expression again. Can I know the reason for this? When I look at the code, it seems like true and false expressions don't matter much.My second question is Couldn't we still control the order of the players with true and false without using swap(which you wrote)?

Comment: Hello.  I just opted to use the modulo 2 (% 2) method just because it would provide a value of either "0" or "1" which happen to be the two indices for your "users" array.  I was just doing that to show a method of switching back and forth when basically one has a binary set of choices.  You most definitely can still use a true/false method as well.  I didn't really know the purpose of the "turn" part so I left that in.